# Creating a docker-compose with PHP drivers for mongo+memcache+ES

Tags: php, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to dockerize an existing application.
Currently the application is *all-in-one* machine that has a PHP server and a web application and mongo + memcache + elastic search.

I'm trying to have the following:
1. Container based of the web application with PHP installed. I think that nimmis/apache-php5 can be a good choice. But I need in that container also PHP drivers for mongo, elastic-search and memcache and I can't get everything to work.
2. Container for MongoDB (thought of using the most popular https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo/)
3. Container for elastic-search
4. Container for memcache.

I thought to wrap it all in a single docker compose file like this (this is not a working example since I have no drivers

```
version:'2'
services:
    web:
        build:.
        volumes:
            -.:/var/www/web
        ports:
            -"80:80"
        links:
            -db:mongo
            -redis
            -memcached:memcached
            -elk
    db:
        image:mongo:latest
        ports:
            -"27017:27017"

    redis:
        image:bitnami/redis:latest
        ports:
        -"6379:6379"

    elk:
        image:sebp/elk
        ports:
            -"5601:5601"
            -"9200:9200"
            -"5044:5044"

    memcached:
        image:memcached:latest
        ports:
            -"11211:11211"
```

I also understand that in my code I will have to replace my localhost reference to mongo with the alias I gave in the links (like db). How will it work once I will move to separate machines ? Any best practices?

Comment: I know it's kinda later, but could you explain what you mean by _I will move to separate machines_? You mean that the _al-in-one_ machine you mentioned earlier will be separate machines? If so, are you willing to run your production application from a container?